# applying current code to another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, vectorization, apply

below is my current code, how do i apply the same code to another Data Frame (importing another excel sheet and apply the same below code to it)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
book= pd.read_csv("book.csv")
book=book.dropna()
book.sort_values("Market Cap", ascending=False, inplace=True)
book = book.head(500)
book["EY"] = (book["Earnings Per Share LTM"] / book["Start Price"])
book["ROIC"] = (book["EBIT"]/ book["Invested Capital"])
book["Price Change"] =((book["Close Price"] - book["Start Price"]) / book["Start Price"])
book['EY Rank'] = book['EY'].rank(ascending=False)
book['ROIC rank'] = book['ROIC'].rank(ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function and call it as many time as you like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def some_func(file_name):
    book= pd.read_csv(file_name)
    book=book.dropna()
    book.sort_values("Market Cap", ascending=False, inplace=True)
    book = book.head(500)
    book["EY"] = (book["Earnings Per Share LTM"] / book["Start Price"])
    book["ROIC"] = (book["EBIT"]/ book["Invested Capital"])
    book["Price Change"] =((book["Close Price"] - book["Start Price"]) / book["Start Price"])
    book['EY Rank'] = book['EY'].rank(ascending=False)
    book['ROIC rank'] = book['ROIC'].rank(ascending=False)
    return book

file_name = "book.csv"
some_func(file_name)
file_name = "next_book.csv"
some_func(file_name)
```

Is this what you look for?

Comment: SSharma , thank you for your answer, yes it is what im looking for, however when i apply and run the function i get an invalid Syntax (File "<ipython-input-8-59b222fd3e49>", line 1
    def some_func("book.csv")
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax)

Comment: Please add your complete code here so that I can help you better.